# Cloud Firestore - Querying for a single document based

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I am working on a project in Angular 6 using Cloud Firestore (still Firebase but not the realtime database). How do I query a collection based on a value i.e. I have a collection of users, each document in the user collection has a field called "id" which has a hash assigned to it. If I have a specific id hash in mind, how can I query the collection to get that document where the id equals the one I have in mind. Also, once I have the document, can I then obtain the document ID that was automatically assigned?

Comment: If it's not firebase realtime database, why did you use that tag? Please make sure you use the correct tags for your question.

Answer (score 1):

For an Angular 6 project you can install [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) which is the the official library for Firebase and Angular.

You can now make a component to achieve your needs:

1- Import the library in your component

```
 import { AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

2 - Injection

```
 constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {}
```

3 - Create your query (ID = yourHash)

```
 this.afs.firestore.collection('users')
        .where('id','==', ID)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                      console.log(doc.id); // id of doc
                      console.log(doc.data()); // data of doc
                })
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will gladly vote this the answer after you make the following corrections:
1. You have an extra dot after collection('users')
2. You have an extra bracket after the where statement
Thanks!

Comment: After getting the doc.id, how can I just return the ID and get the string value?

Comment: The best way to achieve this is to put the part 3 in a function returning a promise and add return statement before 'this.afs......' and after the forEach  return ID. Then call your function which will return you what you need.